# How to get value from user in wordpress custom plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a plugin for wordpress that show a form to users by shortcode, i want submit the form ,get the values and store in defined table that created when my plugin is activated.
Now i don't know where this form should be submit. I define a submenu for plugin in admin panel (and set form action to this submenu slug) to get that value and store in db, but only those how logged in can submit that form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle any form submission using `template_redirect` hook if your form is in the frontend. If your form in the backend then you can use `admin_init` hook

Say, Your form code looks like in front end

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="input_1"/>
    <input type="number" name="input_2"/>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'name_of_your_nonce_action', 'name_of_your_nonce_field' ) ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Now in theme `functions.php` file, you can handle this form like

```
<?php

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp1213_handle_custom_form', 11 );

function wp1213_handle_custom_form() {
    if( ! isset( $_POST['submit_form'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['name_of_your_nonce_field'], 'name_of_your_nonce_action' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Then you can handle all post data ($_POST) and save those data in db
    .......
}
```

Comment: @Sabbir Ahmed what do you mean here "Now in theme `functions.php` file": do you mean you nee to add that code the the `functions.php` file in the theme folder?

Comment: Yes I mean those code need to write in `functions.php` file